# Can we tell search engines (google, yahoo) that a particular website is geographical region specific?

Tags: search-engines, google-search, geolocation, geotargeting, geotagging

I have a website which caters to a specific district. It is of no use if the visitor is from outside this district.

**Question:**
Can I tell/indicate to search engines (mainly google and Yahoo) that this website be included in their search results only if the search is generated from a specific district or a geographic region?

Note: The current domain is country specific.

Comment: Is this a business with a location in that area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

A quick search on Google will reveal this page, from Google's own Support site: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=62399

Essentially, you should set the geographic target in the 'Geographic Target' section in Google Webmaster Tools.

However, since your domain is country-specific, you might not need to. If you want to geographically target people in a certain part of the country however, you should have the address in the footer, for example, where search engines can see it often. This is no no way a sure-fire way of doing it, but as far as I know, it's the only way to at least try.

This sometimes also even get you an automatic pin on Google Maps.

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot tell the Google/Bing to be district specific but you tell the Google that is site is a country specific.

Google will give preference to that site in local searches, i.e country specific. If your site is about a particular district in the country, then I would suggest to get your business listed in Google map, http://maps.google.com/.

This will surely give your site a preferences in searches coming from that district

Comment: As I said in my answer, by having the business address listed in for example the footer, will help Google see very specifically where in an area your site refers to. it's not foolproof, but it does help.

Comment: Having the location info in the footer or even in the content help google to determine the business location. Adding your business in google map and bing map will help more.

Comment: Agreed, adding a local business to Google Maps would help, but unlike adding the address to the website, anyone with 5 minutes of time left over, can add anything to Google Maps. So that data will not alone help drive geographically targeted traffic. Obviously, he should do both since it's not exactly difficult or time consuming :)